# Spring Boot 2 Deployed in wildfly 11 getting error as WFLYSRV0003: Could not index class module-info.class

Tags: java, spring-boot, wildfly

Can anyone help please if faced similar below issue.

**Scenario**: When deploying Spring Boot 2 (Java 8) application as war in Wildlfy 11 getting below WARN error. Though application works fine, still exception in logs not looks fine.

**WARN Error**:

```
944 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-5) WFLYSRV0003: Could not index class module-info.class at //WEB-INF/lib/txw2-2.3.1.jar: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unknown tag! pos=4 poolCount = 18
    at org.jboss.jandex.Indexer.processConstantPool(Indexer.java:1417)
    at org.jboss.jandex.Indexer.index(Indexer.java:1451)
    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.annotation.ResourceRootIndexer.indexResourceRoot(ResourceRootIndexer.java:99)
    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.annotation.AnnotationIndexProcessor.deploy(AnnotationIndexProcessor.java:51)
    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:165)
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:2032)
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1955)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Comment: Update: Deploying in Wildfly 15 does not give error.